# What image format is as simple as ppm format

Tags: image-formats

I want to implement a renderer and save its result as a ppm image because the ppm format is very simple to generate. 
But Windows can't open the ppm image directly. Is there some other simple image format that can be opened in Windows directly.

Comment: What does it mean for Windows to open something "directly"?

Comment: It can be opened using Windows Photo viewer without using other software @ScottHunter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the BMP image format which is very easy to parse and can satisfy my need.

And its wiki URL is below:

[BMP image format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)